# Multi Factor Authentication for your Portal

Tags: web, dotnetnuke, portal, multi-factor-authentication

We are on DNN for our Portal and it can be accessed through a login and password. I would like to understand how can we implement MFA(multi factor Authentication)

Can somebody guide as to what is required. This portal is also further connected with Dynamics 365  for the data. Is there any documentation  that   you could refer  us to?

Thanks,
Jalpa Shah

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an authentication provider for DNN that implements MFA.

If you go to store.dnnsoftware.com and search for "authentication" then you will find some modules.

Note: I don't have any experience with any MFA on DNN, but that's where I would start.

The other option would be to create your own MFA provider.  You might want to poke around the DNN Community section of GitHub, too.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would recommend the usage of a commercial module, such as the one my company makes [DNN Simple 2 Factor Authenticaiton](https://store.dnnsoftware.com/simple-dnn-two-factor-authentication-2fa-030300).

However, you note that you are also looking at a connection with Dynamics 365, which most likely makes that option not a route.

If using Dynamics365 for authentication, you will want to look at configuration within Dynamics to configure/enforce the 2FA processes.